# Cluster kmeans comparison between two data sets

Tags: clustering, k-means, supervised-learning, model-evaluation

I have a situation when I try to see if my data set ("sample") is a good representation of a larger data set ("population") that I have. In Stata, I use the `cluster` command on the both data sets trying to detect patterns that can be later compared for similarity in order to decide if the sample is indeed representative of the population. 1) In Stata, how can I comrade the slitters of the two data sets statistically? 2) In Stata, what else can I do to compare the two data sets for similarity?

Comment: I took the liberty of retagging your question. I am sure that this question has been asked before on CV, and if everything were tagged perfectly, looking for [questions carrying all three of "clustering", "model-evaluation" *and* "supervised-learning"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clustering%2bmodel-evaluation%2bsupervised-learning) (the last because you know a "gold standard" you want to compare your clustering against) should yield what you are looking for. Unfortunately, this search currently yields only two hits, but the other one looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The point is bigger than just clustering.
Try embedding methods like PCA or tSNE on bothe sampled and original data. It will show you similarities of data sets.
Another way is to see the difference between cluster distributions e.g. using Kullback–Leibler divergence. It gives you the distance between two distributions. If it is small your sampling is right.